# Can I replace internal diff in Total Commander with a custom tool?

Tags: diff, total-commander, winmerge

Since I don't really like Total Commander's internal diff *Compare Contents* used in *Compare by content and Synchronize Dirs* → *Compare left & right*, I want to use something else like WinMerge or KDiff3.

Is this possible to launch an external program with the paths to the marked files in the left & right pane? That would solve *Compare by content*. Any other way to solve it? Can I control *Synchronize Dirs* so it does the same when I compare file content there?

Any other suggestions to easily make diffs in Total Commander with external diff program?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are many ways to do this (here I'm using [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) as an example, it's the best I've found in this category, but the solution also works well with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)):

*A) Edit `wincmd.ini` under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\GHISLER\` by default, and add something like this:*

```
[Configuration]
CompareTool=C:\Program Files\Shareware\FileCmp\BeyondCmp\BCompare.exe
```

Now all comparisons are made using this app instead of the internal tool.

---

*B) Using TotalCmd's StartMenu (command "Change start menu..."), add these commands:*

Title:

```
BC (Compare left-vs-right directories)
```

Command:
`%YourPath%\BeyondCmp\BCompare.exe`

Parameters:
`%X%p %X%t`

---

Title:

```
BC (Compare current file under cursor vs same file in the other panel)
```

Command:
`%YourPath%\BeyondCmp\BCompare.exe`

Parameters:
`"%X%p%x%n" "%X%t%x%n"`

---

Title:

```
BC (Compare current file in left vs current file in right)
```

Command:
`%YourPath%\BeyondCmp\BCompare.exe`

Parameters:
`"%X%p%n" "%X%t%m"`

Comment: What is the effect of %X and %x?

Comment: %X Interprets the following parameters after this parameter as left/right instead of source/target: %P, %p (left path), %T, %t (right path), %N, %n (left name), %M, %m (right name), %S, %s (left selected), %R, %r (right selected)

Comment: %x Interprets the following parameters after this parameter again as source/target
    Example: %X%P %x%P sends left and source path to the called program

Comment: To the option A, it worked for me (v8.51a) only if I added the `CompareTool` somewhere near the beginning of the wincmd.ini file. I don't know the exact setting which must be preceded by this, so I'd say the simplest is to put it to the beginning of the file.

Comment: As of TC 9 you can use %C1 %C2 for better emulating the way the internal compare tool works:  %C1 Like the first parameter of "Compare by content" - %C2 Like the second parameter of "Compare by content"

Comment: Thank you very much. Does anyone know what would be the Parameters if I select two different files in the same panel (p.e. 2 files in the right panel)?

Comment: Hint: Under Configuration menu, there is a submenu called "Change ini file directly"

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this question because I wanted to use Visual Studio Code as external diff tool.

Since VS Code isn't primarly a diff tool one can't just invoke the exe-file with two filenames as parameters. Instead the option `--diff` or just `-d` has to be specified.

This is important when editing the WINCMD.INI. The line Comparetool has to take the path  to code.exe and the diff-option:

```
[Configuration]
Comparetool="C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --diff
...
```